# Development of Office 2016 Add ons

Tags: c#, vsto, office-2016

I have already developed Oulook Add on using Visual Studio 2010 with VSTO

It works for OFFice 2007, 2010 and 2013

Now Office 2016 has been released. is the same application will work for 2016?

Is there any changes in VSTO and PIA Version for Office 2016? is those has been released?

if not when will be released? is there any web page to track the release?

If any, Whether i need to install those?

Appreciated for getting a development guidance in Office 2016

Comment: A lot of questions in one question. Have you tried anything? Doesn't sound so.

Comment: Theoretically, the same add-in can be used in 2016. No major changes have been made to VSTO; about the object model (what's reflected in the PIA) you need to ask in an Outlook-specific group. Office 2016 has been released, already months ago.

Comment: @CindyMeister I can confirm the Excel interop has breaking changes particularly with invoking for the Worksheets collection off a Workbook.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have determined the breaking change is an Excel 2016 new workbook contains only 1 worksheet by default. Previous versions created 3.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what PIA version you use in the project. The add-in should work correctly until you use members introduced in newer Office versions. Read more about that in the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx) article.

Note, you can use the late-binding technology for accessing properties, methods and events in newer Office versions even when using older PIAs. See  [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember(v=vs.110).aspx) .

There is no separate installer for Office 2016 PIAs. You can install them as a part of Office 2016. See [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kh3965hw(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information.